# How to call the following script on asp button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook-javascript-sdk

Instead of the default usage of the following script in `div` I would like to call the script on button click

```
 <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1">
        </div>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });
        };

        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement('script');
            js.id = id;
            js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));
    </script>
```

Can some one help me how can I call or execute this script on asp button click event.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

Your code is not complete, I updated the code, this works on my domain, so, it must works also on your
Put this js code in the a.js file, it will be called when the button is pushed:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'your_app_id', // App ID
    channelUrl : 'your_app_domain', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // logged into the app
    alert('logged');
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app
    alert('non logged');
    FB.login();
    } else {
      // not logged into Facebook
    alert('non logged everywhere');
    FB.login();
    }
  });
  };
  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
```

Then put this code to the page where you want to call it, remeber the fb-root div and all the other stuff that fb need:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1">
        </div>
<button onClick="loadit()">ZzZzz</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadit(){
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= 'a.js';
   head.appendChild(script);

}
```

### End edit

You can load a script (for example we call the file a.js), from javascript in this way:
You will put the js code in the file a.js
Checks if it works or it needs some refinement

```
<button onClick="loadit()">ZzZzz</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadit(){
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= 'a.js';
   head.appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

(You don't need to hide the app id, it's visible through js and no one else, except you, can use it out of the domain specified.)

Comment: Hi but the login screen did not appear even though I included it in a script file

Comment: @Learner console errors? Does your code works in a normal situation?

Comment: I didn't logged on with the div just I checked whether log in page is coming or not, no console errors

Comment: @Learner please check the update to the post (the code that you posted it's incomplete)